# recursively finding two elements with the smallest difference in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, difference

I'm trying to recursively find two elements in an array with the smallest difference (assume the array is already sorted in an increasing order).

I've been trying to get my code to just return the smallest sum, but something seems to be not working right with the recursion.

```
public class SmallestDiff {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int [] x = {1,3,6,9,126};
        System.out.println(smallestDiff(x,4));
    }

    public static int smallestDiff (int [] array, int index){
        int result;
        if (index>0){
            int diff = Math.abs((array[index]-array[index-1]));
            result = Math.min (diff, smallestDiff(array,index-1));
        }
        else {
            return array[0];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I asume this should be a training for recursive techniques. In practise your task should be solved with iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is

```
return array[0];
```

`array[0]` is not a difference between values so should not be returned. The simplest way to fix your program is to replace this line with

```
return array[1] - array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

public class SmallestDiff {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = { 1, 3, 6, 9, 126 };

    int result;
    if (x.length < 2) {
        result = x[0];
    }
    else{
        result = smallestDiff(x, x.length-1);
    }
    System.out.println(result);

}

public static int smallestDiff(int[] array, int index) {

    if (index == 0) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    }

    int diff = (array[index] - array[index - 1]);
    return Math.min(diff, smallestDiff(array, index - 1));

}
```

}

This solution prints the first element in case there is only one element in the array. Otherwise, it will always result the smallest difference between two elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is sorted no need for recursion.
The code below solves the problem with iteration.

```
public class SmallestDiff {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {1, 3, 6, 9, 126};
    System.out.println(smallestDiff(x));
}

public static int smallestDiff(int[] array) {
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        int diff = Math.abs((array[i] - array[i + 1]));
        if (diff < result) {
            result = diff;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}